# How can I use validation-api groups with springdoc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc

I'm using validation-api with Springdoc in my Spring boot application.

I want to use single DTO class in similar requests.

Springdoc checks validation-api's annotations, like `@NotBlank`, `@NotNull`. But doesn't check it's groups `@NotBlank(groups = {GetGroup.class})`.

```
public class MyController {
  
  @GetMapping
  public MyResponseDto getFoo(@ParameterObject @Validated(GetGroup.class) MyRequestDto request) {
    ...
  }

  @PostMapping
  public Long postFoo(@ParameterObject @Validated(PostGroup.class) MyRequestDto request) {
    ...
  }
}

public class MyRequestDto {
  
  @NotNull(group = {GetGroup.class})
  private String field01;

  @NotNull(group = {PostGroup.class})
  private String field02;
}
```

The `field01` required in `@Validated(GetGroup.class)`, and `field02` required in `@Validated(PostGroup.class)` without Springdoc.

But Springdoc recognize them required fields.

How can I solve this problem?

This [link](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/510) is same issue.